# Using an array to select vertices in PyMeshLab

Tags: vertices, pymeshlab

I very recently started working with processing 3D objects starting off from files obtained from a 3D scanner. I want to automate the volume calculation (and some other metrics) for my colleagues as this otherwise would become too time-consuming.

In the script, the raw output files (.stl) are read using pymeshlab, split using KMeans clustering, ordered (from top left to bottom right), and further processed. For the splitting, I currently have an array containing the vertices of the different items (indicated by 'true/false' or a number (e.g., 1-n)). I now want to use '`compute_selection_by_condition_per_vertex`' as indicated here ([How to select an array of vertices in pymeshlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68417158/how-to-select-an-array-of-vertices-in-pymeshlab/73004377#73004377)) but with the condition that all vi (vertex indices) that are not in the array should be selected and removed (using '`m.meshing_remove_selected_vertices()`'). The problem is that I don't seem to get the condition right.

```
# Compiling array containing the indices of the vertices of a cluster (tria)
vi_tria = []
    for tria_i,tria_x in enumerate(df['cluster']):
        if tria_x != 1:
            vi_tria.append(tria_i)

# Selecting the vertices in the loaded/selected mesh (tot_mesh) using the array of indices
tot_mesh.compute_selection_by_condition_per_vertex(condselect= "vi==vi_tria")
```

When running this, I get the error:

> pymeshlab.pmeshlab.PyMeshLabException: Failed to apply filter:
> compute_selection_by_condition_per_vertex Details: Unexpected token
> "[] " found at position 4.

I've also tried to put it in a for loop but then PyCharm crashes and I can't find a solution elsewhere on the internet (after already quite some searching). Any help on how I can continue with only a part of the mesh to perform a surface reconstruction on (as there will be a hole in the mesh) afterward would be greatly appreciated!